# How to use the Docker Build Step Jenkins plugin?

Tags: docker, jenkins-plugins

Found this plugin here :

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin

I have installed it in jenkins, but want to learn how to configure and use it.

can anybody help with a sample example?

Comment: That is the only example I have found... In Japanese: http://www.bkjia.com/Linux/1037945.html

Comment: You need to explain _what_ you want to do with the plugin, and what you've tried so far.